# jsf tabledata dynamic inputtext

Tags: jsf, dynamic, input, datatable

I have a List in my backing bean. I want to present it in a table. I want table to have two rows - on left side, values from the list, and on the right side inputBoxes. It's the easy part. Here's my code:

```
<div class="table">
                <h:dataTable id="korekty" styleClass="table table-hover"
                value="#{searchBean.listX}" var="v">
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">XXX</f:facet>
                        #{v.string}
                    </h:column>
                    <h:column>
                        <f:facet name="header">YYY</f:facet>
                        <h:inputText styleClass="form-control">
                        </h:inputText>
                    </h:column>
                </h:dataTable>
            </div>
```

The hard part of my problem is : in those inputtext user might put some numbers. Then after hitting SUBMIT button I want to create a list/map/whatever of inputed values. How can I do that? Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, prepare an array, or a list, containing placeholders for the given data alongside the list you've got:

```
List<String> initialData = ...;//initial data of n size
String[] submittedData = new String[initialData.size()];//array of the same size
```

Then, bind the `<h:dataTable>` component to the view to get access to the current row index of the iteration. This way you can finish your job by binding value of input elements to the corresponding objects in the array/list:

```
<h:dataTable binding="#{table}" ... >
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">YYY</f:facet>
        <h:inputText value="#{searchBean.submittedData[table.rowIndex]}" ... />
    </h:column>
</h:dataTable>
```

Comment: I get error like : `/secure/add_korekta.xhtml @63,88 value="#{searchBean.submittedData[table.rowIndex]}": null`. What might be the problem? I did exactly what you suggested.

Comment: OK - I moved initialization of submittedData to @PostConstruct along with initialization of initialData, and then it worked. Thank you